# React-Native DatePickerIOS minimumDate prop

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am fairly new to react-native and especially working with the DatePickerIOS component. I see that there is a prop `minimumDate` as per the [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html) however I cant seem to find examples of its use anywhere. Basically all I am trying to do is some simple validation so that the user cannot pick a date in the past.

I have tried simply:

```
<DatePickerIOS
  date={this.state.timerDate}
  mode="time"
  timeZoneOffsetInMinutes = {this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
  minuteInterval={1}
  onDateChange = {this._onDateChange}
  minimunDate = {this.state.date}
/>
```

Where `this.state.date`is the current time. But this does not seem to be working at all.

Comment: Is this.state.date a valid Date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean when you say it's not working at all? Are there any errors thrown? Do the rest of the component's features/props function as you would expect?

You have a typo in your example. The prop name should be `minimumDate`, not `minimunDate`.

Comment: this is what happens when you have been writing code for way too many hours and get sloppy. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!